# How to transform a String "a,b,c,d..." into a.b(c,d,...); for execution

Tags: javascript, string

I have a small multiplayer app working in Websockets. The application is composed of a game and a chat object, each with specific methods.

Basically, the client receives a message string formatted like : `"object,method,arg1,arg2"`, that could be for example "chat,newMsg,foo bar", or "game,addPlayer,name,level,team". 
The first example should be translated to `chat.newMsg("foo bar");` while the second example would be `game.addPlayer(name,level,team);` What I am having difficulties doing now is writing the message reader.

I am trying to figure out the most elegant solution, something like :

```
var msgreader = function(message){
  msg=message.split(",");
  msg[1].apply(msg[0],msg[2]);
}
```

But my message can have many arguments, and I can't quite figure out how to handle that. 
Could anyone help me? I will not use eval() ^^

Comment: [Investigate the "apply" function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) Also you'll have to find the object by reference to `window` or something, if that's how things work. Really, if I were in your situation I'd start by fixing the message format.

Comment: Your workflow seems flawed to me. Instead of sending an obscure message, send something you're comfortable with handling.

Comment: Although you can find an example of this in the Google Analytics async code: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking I agree with Madara - you should just send the objects and methods verbatim instead. Send actual Javascript: obj.method(c,d,...); over the wire instead of arrays you have to reinterpret in this extra step, unless there's a reason you can't (like GA's case of there being no GA loaded yet when you enter these commands).

Comment: And then I eval the command received? How to make it in a safe way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply()` expects an array of arguments; if you want to pass arguments individually, use `call()`.

However, `apply()` is best for us in (in the right use case), as we don't know the number of arguments.

```
var msgreader = function (message) {
    var props = message.split(",");
    var obj = window[props[0]];

    obj[props[1]].apply(obj, props.slice(2));
};
```

`apply()` expects the scope as the first parameter, so we provide `obj`. See the documentation for [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

1. This will pass the *strings* `name`, `level`, `team` etc, rather than the value of any variables which have those names.
2. This will ***only*** work if the object you wish to invoke methods on is a global object.

   - If the object you wish to target (`a`) isn't global, but is a property on *another* object (`b`), change `window` to reference `b`.

     ```
     var msgreader = function (message) {
         var props = message.split(",");
         var obj = b[props[0]];

         obj[props[1]].apply(obj, props.slice(2));
     };
     ```
   - Otherwise, you'll *have* to either make your object global, *or* add it as a property to another object.